# has() returns false for Set of multidimensional array?

Tags: javascript, set

I created a Set of 2D arrays like this:

```
let set = new Set([[1, 2], [4, 6]]);
```

now when I am doing `set.has([1, 2])` it returns `false`.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: `[1, 2] === [1, 2]` is always `false` because both the arrays have different reference.

Comment: yes so how can we redefine the equality check for set?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837456/how-to-compare-arrays-in-javascript

Answer (score 4):

If you're going to compare objects or arrays (which aren't primitives, and so aren't `===`), stringify everything in the Set first:

```js
const set = new Set([[1, 2], [4, 6]]);
const setStringified = new Set([...set].map(JSON.stringify));

console.log(setStringified.has(JSON.stringify([1, 2])));
```

Comment: If there's just one item being compared, yeah, there's not much point in creating another Set (using `.some` instead would work instead), but if there are multiple items to check, the Set has less computational complexity

Comment: arrays have an order, sets don't.

Comment: @NinaScholz - Yes they do. The order of entries in a Set is the order they were added. The [[SetData]] in a set is a *list* which is appended to when you add a new value. This is also covered by *"... in original insertion order..."* in Set's [`forEach`](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-set.prototype.foreach). The iterator works by index into [[SetData]], so that's also insertion order (provided you don't modify the set during iteration, which gets ugly because the iterator works by index).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, i know, but `[1, 2, 2]` is as array different, by looking at the values from `[2, 1, 1]`. by taking a set for the values, both are equal.

Comment: @NinaScholz - I don't think the above does that. It converts the set `[[1, 2], [4, 6]]` into the set `["[1,2]", "[4,6]"]` and then uses `has` on `"[1,2]"`. It's not going to confuse `"[2,1]"` for `"[1,2]"`.